# Unity 2d Enemy Spawning not meeting the correct conditions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] enemyPrefabArray;
    public GameObject player;
    [SerializeField] MapGenerator mapGeneratorScript;

    void OnEnable() => mapGeneratorScript.OnGeneratedMap += SpawnMobs;

    void OnDisable() => mapGeneratorScript.OnGeneratedMap -= SpawnMobs;

    void SpawnMobs()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemies(enemyPrefabArray[0], 0.1f, 0.2f, 20, 6));
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnEnemies(GameObject enemyPrefab, float minInterval, float maxInterval, int maxEnemyCount, int withinRangeOfPlayer)
    {
        int numOfEnemies = 0;

        while (numOfEnemies < maxEnemyCount)
        {
            Vector3 playerPos = player.transform.position;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(minInterval, maxInterval));

            int randomXCoord = Mathf.RoundToInt(playerPos.x) + Random.Range(-withinRangeOfPlayer, withinRangeOfPlayer + 1);
            int randomYCoord = Mathf.RoundToInt(playerPos.y) + Random.Range(-withinRangeOfPlayer, withinRangeOfPlayer + 1);

            if (randomXCoord >= 0 && randomXCoord < mapGeneratorScript.map.GetLength(0) && randomYCoord >= 0 && randomYCoord < mapGeneratorScript.map.GetLength(0))
            {
                // Avoiding spawns in water tile
                bool isWaterTile = mapGeneratorScript.map[randomXCoord, randomYCoord] == 1;
                if (!isWaterTile)
                {
                    Instantiate(enemyPrefab, new Vector3(randomXCoord, randomYCoord, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                    numOfEnemies++;
                    Debug.Log($"Player X: {playerPos.x} Player Y: {playerPos.y}, X: {randomXCoord} Y: {randomYCoord}, {mapGeneratorScript.map[randomXCoord, randomYCoord]}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Avoided Spawn on Water");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My issue with my code is the enemies spawn correctly when I stay still after spawning in the game, the enemies spawning in 1 tile and also avoid spawning in the water tile, However whenver i start to move around the map the spawning of the enemies break they spawn off center or in between 2 or more tiles, the enemies also spawn in the water tile.The coardnidates and values in the console from the debug just doesnt match the actual prefabs in the map and i am confused why so?

Here is also a pic of the enemy spawns when i dont move after i spawn
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it0oG.png)
and here is when i move around after i spawn (btw if i stop moving the bug doesnt fix itself)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4uR5.png)

Answer (score 0):

the player's position is constantly changing while the enemy spawning Coroutine is running. When the player moves, the coordinates of the new spawn positions are not calculated accurately.

I have updated Vector3, StartCoroutine and IEnumerator. Run it and see if it works

```
    IEnumerator SpawnEnemies(GameObject enemyPrefab, float minInterval, float maxInterval, int maxEnemyCount, int withinRangeOfPlayer)
{
    int numOfEnemies = 0;

    while (numOfEnemies < maxEnemyCount)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(minInterval, maxInterval));

        Vector3 playerPos = player.transform.position;

        int randomXCoord = Mathf.RoundToInt(playerPos.x) + Random.Range(-withinRangeOfPlayer, withinRangeOfPlayer + 1);
        int randomYCoord = Mathf.RoundToInt(playerPos.y) + Random.Range(-withinRangeOfPlayer, withinRangeOfPlayer + 1);

        if (randomXCoord >= 0 && randomXCoord < mapGeneratorScript.map.GetLength(0) && randomYCoord >= 0 && randomYCoord < mapGeneratorScript.map.GetLength(0))
        {
            // Avoiding spawns in water tile
            bool isWaterTile = mapGeneratorScript.map[randomXCoord, randomYCoord] == 1;
            if (!isWaterTile)
            {
                Instantiate(enemyPrefab, new Vector3(randomXCoord, randomYCoord, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                numOfEnemies++;
                Debug.Log($"Player X: {playerPos.x} Player Y: {playerPos.y}, X: {randomXCoord} Y: {randomYCoord}, {mapGeneratorScript.map[randomXCoord, randomYCoord]}");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Avoided Spawn on Water");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code doesnt work as the plaayerPosition never changes so when the player moves around the enemies only spawn near [0, 0], which is not optimal game experience as you want the enemies to spawn where the player i and the player keeps moving around

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rBb1OER here is the new image the enemies they dont spawn near him which is something i want

Comment: I moved Vector3 playerPos = player.transform.position; inside the loop, this way the Coroutine will take the player's current position each time before it tries to spawn a new enemy. Please run it and see if it fixes your issue